# How to set specific type object for the function parameter ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, typescript

As example, the component received a "valueType", it will cause to use different of the type inside the parameter.

What's the smart way to define the type for it?

```
type ValueTypeOne = "One" | "Two" | "Three";
type ValueTypeTwo = "A" | "B" | "C";

const TestComponent = ({ valueType }) => {
   
  // The valueType is "one", it will use the ValueTypeOne. if valueType is "two", i will assign  it as ValueTypeTwo. 

  // Any smart way to do for the typescript?

  const hello = (value: ValueTypeOne, valueType:"one" ) => {
     const value: Record<ValueTypeOne, string> = {
       One: "Axxx",
       Two: "Bxxxx",
       Three: "Cxxxx"
     }

    return value;
  }

  return (
    <div>....</div>
  )
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just simplify the type extensions hope that will useful

```
import { FC } from 'react';

enum ETypes {
  'One' = 'One',
  'Two' = 'Two',
  'Three' = 'Three',
}

type ValueTypeOne = ETypes;
type ValueTypeTwo = 'A' | 'B' | 'C';

type TestComponentProps = {
  valueType: ValueTypeOne | ValueTypeTwo;
};
const TestComponent: FC<TestComponentProps> = ({ valueType }) => {
  // The valueType is "one", it will use the ValueTypeOne. if valueType is "two", i will assign  it as ValueTypeTwo.

  // Any smart way to do for the typescript?

  const hello = (value: ValueTypeOne, valueT: ETypes.One) => {
    console.log(value, valueT);
    const data: Record<ValueTypeOne, string> = {
      One: 'Axxx',
      Two: 'Bxxxx',
      Three: 'Cxxxx',
    };

    return data;
  };

  return <div>....</div>;
};

export default TestComponent;
```